# .net 6 Razor Pages : Can one have multiple Bind Properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

Totally new to Razor Pages, so forgive my ignorance  (last time I touched anything related was whatever version MVC was at 6 years ago)

In my Index PageModel, I have 2 properties as follows:

```
[BindProperty] public IList<ProviderDto> Providers { get; set; }
[BindProperty] public ProviderSearchParams SearchParams { get; set; }
```

The idea is the first (Providers) are for populating a table.
The second being for a search form on the same page.

My OnGetAsync populate the list and it display just fine in a table (looping over `Model.Providers` )

However when I try add a form to the same page, one `asp-for='` won't autocomplete so I assume what I'm trying to do is not allowed.

So when I post the form in the following code, I simply get a "the page isn't working" error  (I tried any variation I could think of for `asp-for` like `MobileNumber`, `Model.MobileNumber`, `SearchParams.MobileNumber` so I'm kinda sure that's not the problem.

```
@page
@model Web.Pages.Providers.IndexModel
@{
}

<form method="post" >
    <input asp-for="Model.SearchParams.MobileNumber" />
    <button type="submit">find</button>
</form>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>    
                <th>Mobile Number</th>  
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var record in Model.Providers)
            {
                        
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>@record.MobileNumber</strong></td>
                    <td>@record.Name</td>

.....
.....
```

Comment: sounds like you haven't created SearchParams.  Include your controller. (.cs file)

Comment: Could you please share your `IndexModel` details and full `Razor code` along with the backend code so that it can be reproduce easily and then can be resolved quickly.

Comment: Are tag helpers enabled in your ViewImports file https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/#enabling-tag-helpers?

Comment: @MikeBrind put me on the right track.  Did not go look yet but think the problem is those view imports.  The pages in question are in Areas which I might have done wrong  (did not read up on areas, just followed my own head).  So the pages are in /Areas/Providers/Pages/Create...I do have the _ViewStart copied in there but that's it.   Will check after work

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Copied _ViewImports to areas/myarea/pages (just like I did _ViewStart) and all fine.  Thanks pointing me in the  right direction @MikeBrind

Comment: As a general piece of advice, I would avoid using Areas in Razor Pages. You get the same effect by adding a sub folder to your Pages folder without the additional complexity of maintaining an area.